# How to read from a SQLite database in ROBLOX

Tags: sqlite, lua

I literally have to idea how to do that, I thought of using a HTTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roblox provides their own cloud hosted database for free use via their `DataStore` database abstraction API. If you really wanted to, you could create your own database server hosted on something like AWS and allow only specific HTTP headers to retrieve/store information.